# n (node version manager): cannot create directory

Tags: node.js, npm, n

On lubuntu 14.10. I'm trying to update node with "n" (node version manager)

Installed with:

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

without "sudo" it would fail asking for admin privileges...

when trying to use "n", I always get "cannot create directory", "permission denied".

How to make "n" use the proper permissions?

Comment: why would you think `n` can even run without administrative privileges? If you're installing `node` or even just `npm` for all users, the node version manager needs to touch files in the usr/lib dir, which is *very much not accessible* to just any old logged in user, for obvious reasons =)

Comment: If you aren't, there is no benefit in using the `-g` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to install `n` is to use [n-install](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install).

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of `n` tried to create the cache folder `/usr/local/n` no matter what command was run.

Since `n` v3.0.2, the cache folder is only created when needed. This allows you to run read-only command like `n --lts` without using sudo.

(Note that an install does require write permission to the cache folder and to the install folder, so you either need to use sudo, or define N_PREFIX to a writeable location, or change permissions/ownership of the install location.)

Comment: Sorry, already can't remember that I had such an issue. But thanks.

Comment: No worries, I knew the question was *old* and replying for future readers still using old `n`.